# Insert Blank Row after Every New Value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

I hope someone could help with this one. I’m not sure if this is possible but I would like to know if there is any way to insert a blank row after every change of Data in ColumnA(Country) which is the result of a query function.

I want to break on Country (Column A) and Accounts" (Column B) as per the **DesiredOutput** sheet.

Here is the sample file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10R3pOblC3_u6E5-l1LqvaZzMlrZWoVuYrebVMW2wm9w/edit

**BCBA Summary** tab is the result of the query referencing the Raw_Data tab. [image]

The *DesiredOutput* tab is my aim since I will have more than 20 accounts that will be added in the future and it will be easier for me to read the data.

[image]

I wonder if there is any way to get the DesiredOutput?

I tried this [How to automatically insert a blank row after a group of data](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4205954?hl=en), successfully inserted a row, however, it is for every other data. I hope you could help me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome. Would you please add a brief description of your search/research efforts..

Comment: You need whole row blank, totals per country from Pivot table won't do?

Comment: @Oleg S that could be possible with a Pivot table, yes, however, I am trying to make the sheet formula based to make it more dynamic and to avoid manually adjusting the range every time there are new data.

Comment: @XanMei Would you please update your question to show that you want to break on Country (Column A) **and** Accounts" (Column B) as per the "Desired Output" sheet in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to insert a new line at each change of Country (Column A).

There are many ways that this could be done. These have been sourced from: [How to automatically insert a blank row after a group of data.](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4205954?hl=en) on Google Docs Help (Community).

Option #1, based on `TEXTJOIN()`:

`=ArrayFormula(iferror(split(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,if(len('BCBA Summary'!A3:A),{'BCBA Summary'!A3:D,if('BCBA Summary'!A3:A<>'BCBA Summary'!A4:A,";;",";")},)),";",true,false)),",",true,true)))`

**OR**

Option #2, based on `VLOOKUP()`, `SORT()` and `FILTER()`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT({FILTER(ROW('BCBA Summary'!A3:A),'BCBA Summary'!A3:A<>"");FILTER(ROW('BCBA Summary'!A3:A),'BCBA Summary'!A3:A<>"",'BCBA Summary'!A3:A<>'BCBA Summary'!A4:A)+0.5}),{ROW('BCBA Summary'!A3:A),'BCBA Summary'!A3:D},{2,3,4,5},0)))`

Both formula yield the same result.

Comment: Thank you for this one @Tedinoz. I will certainly try this on Monday.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Tedinoz. It is working properly. You really help me a lot. This is the answer I am looking for. I really appreciate your help. :-)